# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on openprocessing with processing.js

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

The code in question is this:

```
void update() {
  int nearbyYou = 0;
  int nearbyWork = 0;
  int nearbyCap = 0;
  int nearbyDead = 0;
  for (int iter = 0; iter < 8; iter = iter + 1) {
    switch nearby[iter] {
      case 0:
        nearbyDead++;
      case 1:
        nearbyYou++;
      case 2:
        nearbyWork++;
      case 3:
        nearbyCap++;
    }
    switch type {
      case 0:
        if (nearbyWork >= 1) {
          type = 1;
        } else {
          type = 0;
        }
      case 1:
        if (nearbyWork >= 1) {
          type = 2;
        } else if (nearbyWork >= 7 || nearbyCap >= 2) {
          type = 3;
        } else {
          type = 0;
        }
      case 2:
        type = 0;
    }
  }
}
}
```

And I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in the processing file

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
https://preview.openprocessing.org/assets/js/vendor/processingjsReleases/processing-1.6.6.js?version=7.42, line 885
https://preview.openprocessing.org/assets/js/vendor/processingjsReleases/processing-1.6.6.js?version=7.42, line 21586
https://preview.openprocessing.org/assets/js/vendor/processingjsReleases/processing-1.6.6.js?version=7.42, line 21623
https://preview.openprocessing.org/sketch/preview/?random=0.24172648490425175, line 49
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js, line 2
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js, line 2
```

I've tried a couple things here and there but I really don't know how to adress this error.

Comment: the *line 885* code is from the processing.js itself, nothing to do with me. And yes, I commented the whole void update() to see if other int x worked and yes they did

Comment: See `https://preview.openprocessing.org/sketch/preview/?random=0.24172648490425175, line 49` so your error should be ocurring on line 49

Comment: The example is not complete and verifiable. What is the last `}` for?

Comment: This probably isn't the solution to your problem, but `switch` statements' cases need to `break`. See [prosssesing-js::switch](http://processingjs.org/reference/switch_/)

Comment: The last } is a mistake, the line 49 is the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know about processingJS. but i quick search proved *int* is a valid keyword. try switch with paranthesis. eg: switch (type) { ... }.

Also you are referencing **nearby**[*index*] but can't see an array **nearby** in your code also the variable **type**, which can only be safely assume both are available within the scope(or are they?).

Also, if you look at the error on the console, you can probably see the line number where the error has been generated.

please always ask with all the necessary code.